# How to save queries in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, query

Is there a way to have a set of saved queries in QGIS?

I want to be able to bring in the same dataset, but with different values on different days, and be able to run certain queries on it with just a quick click rather than going through the query builder.

Answer (score 4):

Using the graphical modeler you can build a generic query and save it.  Then to reduce the number of clicks, in the processing Toolbox under "Models" you will see your queries all ready to be used like a regular plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The first part is easy, as you can add the same layer to the project multiple times and use different queries to make subselections. The second part sounds like plugin territory, so I suggest you take a look at the published plugins, in case something like that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "styles" for that. In the layer tree right click a layer, click add style. For every style create a rulebased renderer with a different query.

If you want to apply this to different layers in combination, you can use the "visibility preset" (the eye icon on top of the layer tree) to store combinations of layer styles.